# Every commaned generates segmentation fault

Tags: linux, terminal

So I was trying to install Linuxbrew, and not having a ton of luck so I used the troubleshooting section of the github site to install it. It appeared everything was working fine, but once the commands finished running something was wrong. Every command I enter gets a segmentation error. Doesn't matter if it's running a shell script using bash or something as simple as `bash --version`. Code block from Homebrew/Linuxbrew that messed me up below.

```
prefix=~/.linuxbrew
PATH="$prefix/bin:$prefix/sbin:$PATH"
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
ln -s $(which gcc) $prefix/bin/gcc-$(gcc -dumpversion |cut -d. -f1,2)
ln -s $(which g++) $prefix/bin/g++-$(g++ -dumpversion |cut -d. -f1,2)
ln -s $(which gfortran) $prefix/bin/gfortran-$(gfortran -dumpversion |cut -d. -f1,2)
brew install hello && brew test -v hello; brew remove hello
sudo yum install gcc44 gcc44-c++
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc44 $prefix/bin/gcc-4.4
ln -s /usr/bin/g++44 $prefix/bin/g++-4.4
ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran44 $prefix/bin/gfortran-4.4
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.4
brew install hello && brew test -v hello; brew remove hello
brew install glibc
brew remove binutils
brew unlink glibc
brew test glibc
brew install hello && brew test -v hello; brew remove hello
ln -s lib $prefix/lib64
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/zlib.rb
brew install binutils
brew install hello && brew test -v hello; brew remove hello
brew link glibc
ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 $prefix/lib/
brew install gcc --with-glibc -v
rm -f $prefix/lib/{libstdc++.so.6,libgcc_s.so.1}
brew link gcc
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9
brew install hello && brew test -v hello; brew remove hello
brew install curl expat git
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install bzip2 coreutils findutils gawk gnu-sed gnu-which grep libpng libxml2 libxslt make ncurses readline ruby
PATH=$prefix/bin:$prefix/sbin
brew install hello && brew test -v hello; brew remove hello
ln -s ncursesw/curses.h $prefix/include
```

Any idea how to get back to the point where terminal will actually allow me to do, well, anything? I'm on Linux RedHat

Comment: you've probably trashed your system by replacing/corrupting some core system library, e.g glibc

Comment: Please add more information. You executed that as root or provided your root pass during install? Can you reboot and login as a different user? If so you get the same problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the issues caused by the above script we rebuilt the .bashrc file from the ground up.